# How to change the default installation directory to user home (on windows).?

Tags: installation, install4j

I'm using install4j 6.1.6. Does anyone know how to default the installation directory to user home (on windows).?

At the moment its defaulting to Program Files directory and I dont want to install the application on that directory.

I tried setting a variable as below, 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the media wizard, go to the "Installer options" step, select the "Use custom installation base directory" check box and enter `~`.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, that was the solution I was looking for ... I went doing the following ( I'm sure its not the correct way of doing )  - Run a script in in the installation steps and  added the script as  ( context.setInstallationDirectory( new File( Util.getUserHome() + "\\<APP_NAME>" ));
return true; )

Comment: Yes, you can do that too, although in that case I would add the script to the "Startup" node.

Comment: @IngoKegel I tried this and it gives c:\users\<username>\AppName as default directory. How can I set it as <SystemDrive>:\AppName  as default?

Comment: @Ram In 7.0.8 you will be able to set it to `${SystemDrive}` or any other environment variable. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.

Comment: I'm using an older version of install4j (5.x).  Can this be done such that the base directory is just C:\

Comment: @tale852150 Yes, you can just enter c:\